# One button works, the other one doesn't

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have two input buttons. One to set the MySQL database value to 0 the other to set it to 1. I have got the input button to succesfully set the value to 1. The select button does not do anything.

I'm using PHP, MYSQL, JQUERY, and AJAX

Here is all of my code

```
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="insert" value="insert"/>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="select" value="select"/>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.button').click(function(){
            var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
            var ajaxurl = '<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/actions/settings.php',
            data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                // Response div goes here.
                alert("This is where the success message goes.");
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
```

**`settings.php`**

```
<?php

include_once (__DIR__ . "/../oc-config.php");

if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'insert':
            insert();
            break;
        case 'select':
            select();
            break;
    }
}

function select() {
  $site = BASE_URL;
  $link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

  if (!$link)
  {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $query = "UPDATE settings SET setting_status='0' WHERE `setting_name='CIV_REG'";

  try
  {
      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $uid);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

      if ($result == false)
      {
          die(mysqli_error($link));
      }
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
      die("Failed to run query: " . $e->getMessage());
  }

  mysqli_close($link);

  session_start();
  $_SESSION['accessMessage'] = '<div class="alert alert-success"><span>Allowed Civilian Registration</span></div>';

  sleep(1);
  header("Location:".BASE_URL."/oc-admin/settingsManagement.php");
}

function insert() {
  $site = BASE_URL;
  $link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

  if (!$link)
  {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $query = "UPDATE settings SET setting_status='1' WHERE setting_name='CIV_REG'";

  try
  {
      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $uid);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

      if ($result == false)
      {
          die(mysqli_error($link));
      }
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
      die("Failed to run query: " . $e->getMessage());
  }

  mysqli_close($link);

  session_start();
  $_SESSION['accessMessage'] = '<div class="alert alert-success"><span>Allowed Civilian Registration</span></div>';

  sleep(1);
  header("Location:".BASE_URL."/oc-admin/settingsManagement.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: Please add [relevant] snippets of your code instead of just linking to pastebin.

Comment: It's important to keep your question as self-contained as possible. Off-site links are annoying and problematic for many people.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't figure out the whole indention thing, I tried putting my code inside of the code blocks but it was not parsing it and showing as plain text.

Comment: Hi, you can paste your code inside your text, select it then press `Ctrl + K` this would make it as code.

Comment: you should remove this `header("Location:".BASE_URL."/oc-admin/settingsManagement.php");` from your functions, as this script will be called via ajax it doesn't make sense.

Comment: _"The select button does not do anything"_ - how far do you get? Do you reach the correct `switch ($_POST['action']) {`? Do you reach the `function select()`?

Comment: When I click on the insert button, the value gets changed to 1 in the database, and get the alert saying success after a second or two. When I click on the select button I get the alert message immediately and the value remains as 1. That's all I can tell you, i'm learning and don't know very much. I'm very sorry.

Comment: Please read articles about 'how to debug'. You always need to check which exact part of your code is failing. You actually would have received the `die("Failed to run query: " . $e->getMessage());`

Comment: @MattlGaming see answer below it will be fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missing backtick " ` " for the column name `setting_name` in your query inside the `select()` function change your query

from

```
 $query = "UPDATE settings SET setting_status='0' WHERE `setting_name='CIV_REG'";
```

to

```
$query = "UPDATE settings SET `setting_status`='0' WHERE `setting_name`='CIV_REG'";
```

Comment: Oh my god I am so stupid wow. thank you so much because I had no idea why it wasnt working

Comment: lol it happens with everyone glad it worked for you @MattlGaming